# Error: Service firestore is not available - Clon Tinder con firebase y react

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Estoy intentando hacer un clon de tinder con react y firebase.

Me sale el error que especifique en el titulo.

```
Error: Service firestore is not available
```

Tengo la database en 'firebase.js' y el componente que debería renderizar las tarjetas en 'TinderCards.js'

Código en `firebase.js`:

```javascript
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
export default database;
```

y el código en `TinderCards.js` seria el siguiente:

```javascript
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import database  from './firebase';
import {onSnapshot, collection, query, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

function TinderCards() { 
    const [persona, setPersona] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const q = query(collection(database, "personas"))
        const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {        
            setPersona(querySnapshot.docs.map(d => doc.data() ))
        });
        return () => {
            unsub();
        }
    }, [])
}
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda!!
Espero no olvidarme nada

Comment: Podrías intentar hacer la importación de la función `getFirestore` desde `'firebase/firestore/lite'` como recomienda la [documentación oficial de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?hl=es-419#access-firebase)

Comment: Hola Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza, gracias por contestar;
Al cambiar el patch de importacion y agregar lite me sale otro error el cual especifico:

FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore


Que opinas que puede llegar a ser el problema?

Estoy siguiendo alpie de la letra las indicaciones de un tuto de youtube, pero como se actualizo varias veces Firebase en este tiempo quedo obsoleto.

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Firebase estás usando? Puedes fijaste en tu `package.json`.